# Ignoring all but certain text

Tags: macros

I'm wondering if there's a way to define a command so that, when a flag is specified, I can ignore everything but text within the tag.  For instance, if I had

```
...
This is a \dontignore{bird}.
```

I would want the output to be either "This is a bird." or "bird" depending on whether or not I switch this flag.

Is this doable?  Obviously surrounding everything but the text I want in some tag would be easy, but that seems quite inelegant.

Edit: Here's exactly what I have in mind:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dontignore}[1]{...}
\begin{document}
Hello world.  This is my full document with a lot of extra bells and whistles and lines.  But in the end, \dontignore{this is all that matters}.
\end{document}
```

With the flag off, the output should be

> Hello world.  This is my full document with a lot of extra bells and whistles and lines.  But in the end, this is all that matters.

Otherwise,

> this is all that matters

Optimally, I would also be able to tell LaTeX not to ignore things like section and enumerate/itemize/item commands as well, as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dontignore}[1]{...}
\begin{document}
\section{First part}
Hello world.  This is my full document with a lot of extra bells and whistles and lines.  But in the end, \dontignore{this is all that matters}.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \dontignore{Item 1}
  \item Something like \dontignore{Item 2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

to produce either everything (eg, with dontignore defined as \newcommand{\dontignore}[1]{#1}) or otherwise (with some flag specifying section, enumerate, etc.) as follows

> ## 1 First part
>
> this is all that matters
>
> 1. Item 1
> 2. Item 2

Comment: So you want to get rid of `This is a` part depending on the context?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) How should (La)TeX determine where the to-be-ignored part ends? What about `...` before the line and `.` at the end? What is with text following that line? Do you want to ignore the whole `document` environment except for the `\dontignore` parts? Can you provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Are you looking for something like: `\mycmd{This is a \dontignore{bird}}`  Or do you want the entire document to disappear outside of the `\dontignore{}` tags?

Comment: I added my MWE.  As percusse said, I initially wanted to get rid of the `This is a`, but optimally I would like to be able to compile and tell the compiler to ignore all text outside of specific commands or environments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

---

[image]

---

In the following you get one or the other output shown above depending on whether this line is commented out or not

```
%\let\ignoreflag\relax
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\long\def\dontignore#1{#1}
\makeatletter

\long\def\ignoreflag{%
\@makeother\{%
\@makeother\}%
\xignore}
\long\def\xignore#1\dontignore#2{%
\catcode`\{\@ne
\catcode`\}\tw@
\afterassignment\xxdontignore\toks@\bgroup}
\long\def\xxdontignore{%
\the\toks@\ignoreflag}
\makeatother

%\let\ignoreflag\relax
\begin{document}
\ignoreflag

This is some text 

\begin{itemize}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\item ccc \dontignore{hello }
\end{itemize}

more text 
\dontignore{
\begin{enumerate}
\item this
\item that
\end{enumerate}
}

more stuff

\dontignore{\end{document}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks perfect, although I can't say that I understand anything that you wrote.  Do you know of any resources that might help me understand it?

Comment: texbook or (free) tex by topic or this site (search for `delimited macros`)

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifToggle \Togglefalse % change to \Toggletrue
\makeatletter
\def\myText#1{\expandafter\myText@i#1\@nil}
\def\myText@i#1\dontignore#2\END#3\@nil{\ifToggle#1\fi#2\ifToggle#3\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\myText{%
Hello world.  This is my full document with a lot of extra 
bells and whistles and lines.  But in the end, \dontignore this 
is all that matters \END some more text.}
\end{document}
```

with `\Toggletrue` all text is printed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a LuaTeX based solution (in ConTeXt)

- I assume that the content is surrounding in an environment `\startignore` ... `\stopignore`.
- Ignoring is enabled or disabled using a [mode](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes) (and, therefore, can be controlled via the command line)
- The gobbling of everything not inside `\dontignore{...}` tags is done in Lua using an [lpeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/) parser that captures the contents `\dontignore`. The parser handles nested `{...}` correctly.

I don't know the LuaLaTeX equivalent of ConTeXt buffers, so I am not sure how to translate this to LuaLaTeX.

```
\let\dontignore\firstofoneargument

\startluacode
    local lpegmatch, patterns = lpeg.match, lpeg.patterns
    local P, V, Cs, C = lpeg.P, lpeg.V, lpeg.Cs, lpeg.C
    local format = string.format


    local backslash    = P("\\")
    local csname       = backslash * P("dontignore") 
    local whitespace   = lpeg.patterns.whitespace 
    local leftbrace    = P("{")
    local rightbrace   = P("}")
    local nonbrace     = 1 - leftbrace - rightbrace
    local nested       = P { leftbrace * (nonbrace + V(1))^0 * rightbrace }
    -- I am not sure if it makes sense to add spaces around the captured text or
    -- not. Below I assume that you want spaces around the next. If not, then
    -- you can just use
    --      local value        = P(csname * whitespace^0 * leftbrace * C((nested + nonbrace)^0) * rightbrace) / context
    local value        = P(csname * whitespace^0 * leftbrace * C((nested + nonbrace)^0) * rightbrace) / (function(s) context(" %s ", s) end)
    local nonvalue     = (1 - value)
    local parser       = ( (nonvalue^0 * value * nonvalue^0)^0 )

    thirddata = thirddata or {}

    local getcontent = buffers.getcontent

    -- Function that ignores all the data except that in \dontignore
    thirddata.ignoredata = function (name) 
        lpegmatch(parser, getcontent(name))
    end
\stopluacode

\unexpanded\def\startignoring
    {\grabbufferdata[ignorebuffer][startignoring][stopignoring]}

\unexpanded\def\stopignoring
    {\doifmodeelse{ignore}
        {\ctxlua{thirddata.ignoredata('ignorebuffer')}}
        {\getbuffer[ignorebuffer]}}
```

This can be used as follows

```
\starttext

\enablemode[ignore]

\startignoring
  \startitemize[n]
    \item This is \dontignore{item 1}
    \item And this is \dontignore{item 2}
  \stopitemize
\stopignoring

\disablemode[ignore]

\startignoring
  \startitemize[n]
    \item This is \dontignore{item 1}
    \item And this is \dontignore{item 2}
  \stopitemize
\stopignoring

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

The advantage of parsing content in Lua is that the anything outside `\dontignore` does not need to be valid TeX code. Therefore, even something like

```
\startignoring
  \undefined \dontignore{Does this work} 
\stopignoring
```

works correctly (of course, this will fail when ignore mode is disabled).