# Ignoring or Having a part of a text

Tags: xetex

I want to revise my paper so some sentences must be Deleted/Added/Revised. I need two versions of the manuscript:

- with Deleted sentences,
- without Deleted sentences.

I used the template presented in the question:
[Ignoring all but certain text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95072/ignoring-all-but-certain-text)

However, I have some problems:

1. When I use `\‎let\ignoreflag\relax`‎‎‎ and compile my code (based on xelatex), the distances between three different types of sentences are omitted.

[image: Image 1]

2. and when I omit using `\‎let\ignoreflag\relax‎‎‎`, I get the following error:

   > "! Argument of \xignore has an extra }.  \par"

and again, the distances between two different types of sentences are omitted.

[image: Image 2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\long\def\dontignore#1{#1}
\makeatletter
\long\def\ignoreflag{\@makeother\{\@makeother\}\xignore}
\long\def\xignore#1\dontignore#2{\catcode`\{\@ne\catcode`\}\tw@\afterassignment\xxdontignore\toks@\bgroup}
\long\def\xxdontignore{\the\toks@\ignoreflag}
\makeatother
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\mydelete}[1]{\color{red}{\ignoreflag\sout{#1}}\color{black}}
\newcommand{\myadd}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}\color{black}}
\newcommand{\need}[1]{\textsc{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}}}
\let\ignoreflag\relax
\begin{document}
\dontignore
This is some text: \mydelete{I want to IGNORE this text OR TAKE IT INTO ACCOUNT} \myadd{I want to ADD this text} \need{I want to REVISE this text.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the phrase, "the distances between two different types of sentences are omitted"?  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Thank you. Please see Image 1. The blank spaces are deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what all that `\ignoreflag` stuff is trying to accomplish, but couldn't you approach it more simply?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\ORIGmydelete}[1]{\textcolor{red}{‎‎‎‎\sout{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myadd}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\need}[1]{\textsc{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}}}
\newcommand\ignore{\renewcommand\mydelete[1]{\ignorespaces}}
\newcommand\dontignore{\let\mydelete\ORIGmydelete}
\dontignore
\begin{document}‎     ‎ ‎
This is some text:‎ ‎\mydelete{I want to IGNORE this text OR TAKE IT INTO ACCOUNT} ‎‎\myadd{I want to ADD this text}‎ ‎\need{I want to REVISE this text.}

\ignore
This is some text:‎ ‎\mydelete{I want to IGNORE this text OR TAKE IT INTO ACCOUNT} ‎‎\myadd{I want to ADD this text}‎ ‎\need{I want to REVISE this text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution you are referring to provides a way of hiding (or not hiding) all text that is not included in a `\dontignore`. Since you only want to hide a small portion of your text, you would need to include all the text you write in `\dontignore` commands except for the `\mydelete` parts.

So instead of using that solution, I would suggest to do something much easier, like this:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{ignoreflag}
\newcommand{\mydelete}[1]{\iftoggle{ignoreflag}{}{#1}}
\toggletrue{ignoreflag} %don't print the text
\togglefalse{ignoreflag} %print the text
```

(or the way it is done in Steven's answer). Since only `\mydelete` shall be effective, you only need to have a short switch inside the `\mydelete` definition to either print something or not. (This part is inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5896/103046).)

To your other question: Spaces after your macros are ignored. You can manually change this by adding another `{}` after each macro, or adding an explicit space `\`. Since this is rather cumbersome, you can use the `xspace` package like this:

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\myadd}[1]{#1\xspace}
```

which automatically detects whether a space needs to be added after the macro or not. There are, however, several people who advise not to use `xspace`, so read [their arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/103046) before deciding to do so.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{ignoreflag}
\newcommand{\mydelete}[1]{\iftoggle{ignoreflag}{}{\color{red}{\sout{#1}}\color{black}\xspace}}
\newcommand{\myadd}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}\color{black}\xspace}
\newcommand{\need}[1]{\textsc{\textcolor{Maroon}{#1}}\xspace}

\begin{document}

\toggletrue{ignoreflag}
This is some text: \mydelete{I want to IGNORE this text OR TAKE IT INTO ACCOUNT} \myadd{I want to ADD this text} \need{I want to REVISE this text.}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\togglefalse{ignoreflag}
This is some text: \mydelete{I want to IGNORE this text OR TAKE IT INTO ACCOUNT} \myadd{I want to ADD this text} \need{I want to REVISE this text.}

\end{document}
```

[image]